# Shamir SS: To associate shares to the public values $x_i$, when the shares are permuted

Tags: cryptanalysis, protocol-design, secret-sharing

Suppose we use $(t,n)$ Shamir secret sharing as follows:

- We share the secret $\beta$ as $S=[s_1,..., s_n]$, where $X=[x_1,...,x_n]$ are the public values. For the sake of simplicity, lets assume that $n>100$ and $t=2$.
- We permute the elements in the vector $S$.

---

**Question 1:** Given the permuted vector, can an adversary associate each share to the corresponding $x_i$ values? if yes/no why?

Edit:

**Question 2:** What if we mix the shares with some dummy values and then we permute all, and give them to the adversary?

Comment: Comments are neither for providing answers, nor for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35102/discussion-on-question-by-user153465-shamir-ss-to-associate-shares-to-the-publi).

Comment: As an aside: to clean up things, I’ve moved out conversation to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35124/discussion-between-e-sushi-and-user153465) too. ;)